# graph layout in IE rendered wrong, Chrome works fine

Tags: d3.js

first of all here is the link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HotFrost/RnNX3/6/
you can see that in chrome the graph layout inside the svg element, panned and zoomed ok. Whereas for IE (v9.0) it totally disregards the borders.

basically for this simple layout:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content-col"> graph 
        <div id="graphwidget_graphContainer" style="border: 4px solid purple;" ></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-col"> menu </div>
</div>
```

IE and Chrome render graph differently.

I have tried to use different settings for width/height/remove them. I have tried to replace the divs with table cells.. Still same problem - in IE graph nodes are rendered above the svg element and then (when panned/zoomed) also go over the svg element borders.

Anyone can give some ideas how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

HF